# php addslashses changes string and convert character into special character

Tags: php

I have the following string.

```
$str = "All photos saved to property drive: T:\The Station - State College\Quarterly tests\2023\Q2";
```

After using the addslashes function:

```
echo addslashes($str);
```

Output as :

```
All photos saved to property drive: T:\\The Station - State College\\Quarterly tests�3\\Q2
```

Why string changes for \20 ? Any way to keep the string as it is.

Comment: _"Why string changes for \20 ?"_ - it didn't. `echo $str;` would have gotten you the output `[...] Quarterly tests�3\Q2` already.

Comment: Because you used double quotes as string delimiters, `\202` was interpreted as an octal character reference, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: `addslashes()` barely has real life usages. What are you trying to accomplish?